# Get graphic of TableCell

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, tablecell, tablecolumn

I have implemented a custom TableCell & TableColumn to show a hyperlink while the cell is not editing. I want to add setOnAction event for the hyperlink. As i want to reuse the TableCell i cannot add the code in TableCell updateItem method. Is there any way to implement this?

```
public class TableColumnHyperlink<S> extends TableColumn<S, String> {

    public TableColumnHyperlink (String header) {
        super(header);
        Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> hypCellFactory =
            (TableColumn<S, String> p) -> new TableCellHyperlink();

        setCellFactory(hypCellFactory);
    }
}
```

And the TableCell implementation is

```
public class TableCellHyperlink<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {

    private final TextField textField;
    private final Hyperlink hyperlink;

    public TableCellHyperlink() {

        textField = new TextField();
        hyperlink = new Hyperlink();
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty && (getTableRow() == null ? true : getTableRow().isEmpty()));
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if(isEditing()) {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(null);
                hyperlink.setText(getString());
                setGraphic(hyperlink);
            }
        }
    }


    private void createTextField() {
        textField.setText(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent t) -> {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return (getItem() != null)?getItem():"";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. You can just do `hyperlink.setOnAction( event -> ...);` in the `TableCellHyperlink` constructor. But I think I'm missing the problem...?

Comment: yes James_D. Since I want to reuse TableCellHyperlink across multiple TableView, the behavior of the hyperlink will be different each time. Setting hyperlink.setOnAction inside TableCellHyperlink will not make the class generic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the event handler implementation will vary by instance, you need to pass the event handler (or a function) into the constructor. Since you probably need to access the cell, you'll do something like

```
public class TableCellHyperlink<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {

    private final TextField textField;
    private final Hyperlink hyperlink;


    public TableCellHyperlink(Consumer<TableCellHyperlink<S> handlerFunction) {

        textField = new TextField();
        hyperlink = new Hyperlink();
        hyperlink.setOnAction(event -> handlerFunction.accept(this));
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you can do something like

```
TableCellHyperlink<MyType> hyperlinkCell = new TableCellHyperlink<>(cell -> {
    MyType rowValue = (MyType) cell.getTableRow().getValue(); // getTableRow() returns TableRow, not TableRow<MyType>
    String cellValue = cell.getItem();
    // implement action
});
```

Obviously you can move the parameter up and pass it into the custom TableColumn constructor if you like.